# How to separate tuple into independent pandas columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with matching two separate dataframes on first name using [HMNI](https://github.com/Christopher-Thornton/hmni)'s fuzzymerge.

On output each row returns a key like: (May, 0.9905315373004635)

I am trying to separate the Name and Score into their own columns. I tried the below code but don't quite get the right output - every row ends up with the same exact name/score in the new columns.

```
for i, v in enumerate(matched.key):
matched['MatchedNameFinal'] = (matched.key[i][0][0])
matched['MatchedNameScore'] = (matched.key[i][0][1])
```

matched[['consumer_name_first', 'key','MatchedNameFinal', 'MatchedNameScore']]

[image]

Comment: Might be better to fix this _before_ that list of a single tuple was stored in the DataFrame. Presumably, you could have turned that output into a 2 column DataFrame that you concat to the original DataFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first when going over rows in pandas is better to use apply

```
matched['MatchedNameFinal'] = matched.key.apply(lambda x: x[0][0])
matched['MatchedNameScore'] = matched.key.apply(lambda x: x[0][1])
```

and in your case I think you are missing a tab in the for loop

```
for i, v in enumerate(matched.key):
    matched['MatchedNameFinal'] = (matched.key[i][0][0])
    matched['MatchedNameScore'] = (matched.key[i][0][1])
```

Comment: Ah right, didn't even consider using apply. That works perfectly thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you want to avoid using `enumerate` for `pandas` because `pandas` functions are vectorized and much faster to execute.

So this solution won't iterate using `enumerate`.

First you turn the list into single tuple per row.

`matched.key.explode()`

Then use zip to split the tuple into 2 columns.

`matched['col1'], matched['col2'] = zip(tuples)`

Do all in 1 line.

```
matched['MatchedNameFinal'], matched['MatchedNameScore'] = zip(*matched.key.explode())
```